# Are IR phototransistors always dark, are IR LEDs always clear?

Tags: infrared, phototransistor

I've been working through the "Electronic Circuits for the Evil Genius" guide and someone bought me a components kit for the guide specifically. I already have some phototransistors where the plastic is dark in color and I've seen ones before that are dark in color. Also the guide says that they are dark in color. However when I assemble the circuit, its obvious that the components provided by the kit are reversed in color. The dark plastic LED is generating the IR light and the phototransistor is in a clear plastic form that looks like an LED. I can prove this by simply removing the dark LED and pointing an IR remote at the clear part and it will rapidly flash the red notification LED.

So obviously not all phototransistors are dark and not all IR LEDs are clear. Is there a rule or is it just based on the manufacturer's decision?

Comment: Just to muddy the waters a bit you may find that many LEDs also have a weak photo-sensitivity that is detectable when desperate for some response or in an emergency when you need a sensor and have no photo transistors to hand.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I've seen a few other pages talk about this ability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dark part of the IR phototransistor is often called *daylight filter*.  It's there to make the IR phototransistor less sensitive to visible light.  (Be aware that the sunlight has got plenty of IR too.)

I have looked up two phototransistors: both are made by the same manufacturer, both have the same mechanical package, both have peak sensitivity in the 900nm to 940nm region.  One has got clear lens, the other one has got a daylight filter.  Let's compare them.  Notice that the dark one is less sensitive in the visible light region.

[image]
[image]
([datasheet](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Everlight%20PDFs/PT908-7C-F.pdf))

[image]
[image]
([datasheet](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Everlight%20PDFs/PT908-7B-F.pdf))

Comment: Ok thanks for the example and how it affects sensitivity. So there are obviously not all dark. So do you know if the dark part on an IR LED have the same affect?

Comment: The dark plastic on an LED may be more cosmetic, the LED is generating the light at a pretty narrow wavelength spread so a simple pigment or dye in the plastic is unlikely to be able to change the frequency response by much other than attenuating it.

Comment: So far, I have seen IR LEDs that are clear, blue and violet.  I'm sure other colors are possible.  There's no need for a "black" pigment, as it doesn't matter if visible light enters the LED.

Answer (score 0):

Hi just ran into this myself.  I got my kit from ABRA electronics, and they packaged the 5mm IR set rather than the 3mm IR set.  If you look up their respective descriptions on the ABRA site, you will see that the 3mm set, the dark glass is the phototransistor, and in the 5mm set, its the other way around.

Also helpful in the discription is how to identify the collector (short lead) on the transistor.

https://abra-electronics.com/opto-illumination/infrared-optics/3mm-infrared-emitter-and-sensor-set-ir-set-3mm.html

https://abra-electronics.com/opto-illumination/infrared-optics/5mm-infrared-emitter-and-sensor-set-ir-set-5mm.html

Comment: Actually my mistake, the two sets are the same (emiiter Blue, phototransitor clear), however they ARE opposite from the book.